# The ParameterView instance can no longer be read because it has expired. ParameterView can only be read synchronously and must not be stored for

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

When overriding SetParametersAsync, if I call any asynchronous method then I get the "Unhandled exception rendering component: The ParameterView instance can no longer be read because it has expired. ParameterView can only be read synchronously and must not be stored for later use."

```
public override async Task SetParametersAsync(ParameterView parameters)
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);

    await base.SetParametersAsync(parameters);
}
```

How can we safely call an async method in SetParamatersAsync?

Comment: Just to note, [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-5.0#after-parameters-are-set) say you just shouldn't do this: _"Asynchronous work when applying parameters and property values must occur during the OnParametersSetAsync lifecycle event."_

Comment: I'm not sure if that doc text means that.  In my case (the real world problem, not my simplified example), I need to perform an async operation to call a server based on the state passed into the component before OnParametersSetAsync.  It wouldn't work inside OnParametersSetAsync.  Also, if async calls are not applicable here, then what would be the the purpose of an overridable SetParametersAsync method?

Comment: Well, Shaun's answer solves it and that's probably also the 'purpose' of this method, setting the params DIY.

Comment: I think a lot of people misunderstand components and the life cycle. `SetParametersAsync` is called by the rendering process when one or more of the component's parameters have been changed.  You need to be polite and use the `ParameterView` object you've been passed quickly so it can be disposed.  What happens after that is entirely up to the component.  Normally change a few things and queue a render fragment by calling StateHasChanged.  The ComponentBase code is here https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Components/Components/src/ComponentBase.cs.  It's worth getting to know.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I believe the coding patterns you're looking for are shown below.  The error message is generated by the Renderer.  It's passing in the `ParameterView`, tracks it, and expects it to be consumed immediately (synchronously).  The parameters within the object could be very stale in a second.

In the pattern we consume `parameters` immediately, applying it to the component instance properties.  We can then call `base` at our leisure, passing an empty `ParameterView` as we've already set them.

```cs
        public async override Task SetParametersAsync(ParameterView parameters)
        {
            parameters.SetParameterProperties(this);
            await Task.Delay(100);
            await base.SetParametersAsync(ParameterView.Empty);
        }
```

```cs
        public override Task SetParametersAsync(ParameterView parameters)
        {
            parameters.SetParameterProperties(this);
              ... Do things
            return base.SetParametersAsync(ParameterView.Empty);
        }
```

This is the pattern the ASPNetCore team seem to use.  You can see it here in the code for [InputBase - line 190 onwards](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Components/Web/src/Forms/InputBase.cs).

Comment: This works great - thanks. One question - is the final call passing `SetParametersAsync(ParameterView.Empty)` because it previously called `SetParameterProperties(this)`? It seems weird this is needed.

Comment: You have to pass in a valid `ParameterView`.  You can't pass in a `null`, you shouldn't pass in the original as you don't want to set them again (they may have changed in the meantime and the set is an expensive reflection operation), so you pass in an empty set and `parameters.SetParameterProperties(this);` in the base class does nothing.